# Unable to run :PackerSync on neovim

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

So I wanted to lazy-load packer on certain commands, mostly just `:PackerSync`, but including some more. So in my `plugins.lua` file in `~/.config/nvim/lua`, I added `opt = true` to enable lazy loading, and for certain commands, I added `cmd = {'PackerCompile', 'PackerClean', 'PackerInstall', 'PackerUpdate', 'PackerSync', 'PackerStatus', 'PackerLoad'}` to start packer on those commands. Also, according to [Packer's official GitHub Repository](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim), it told you to add `vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]` if you "[have packer configured as `opt`](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim#bootstrapping:%7E:text=have%20packer%20configured%20as%20%60opt%60)", in which I did, but I followed my own rules in hopes that my code will be more readable, but that will function the same, in which I did first tried `vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]` before doing my `vim.cmd('packadd packer.nvim')`, and it worked pretty much the same. And of course, I didn't forget to add `require('plugins')` in my `init.lua` in `~/.config/nvim`. So after all that—and by the way I have not installed anything beforehand, so this is a completely clean installation—, I ran `:PackerSync`, which, when I ran for the first time, worked, meaning it did indeed show up, never mind it hadn't successfully installed a plugin ([SnipRun](https://github.com/michaelb/sniprun)) that I have configured in the `plugins.lua` file, in which I had multiple attempts trying to installed it by pressing `R` but failed. I tried again by reopening nvim and running that very command (`:PackerSync`), but this time, Packer didn't even show up, only a red error message spat in my face:

```
Error in packer_compiled: ...vim/site/pack/packer/opt/packer.nvim/lua/packer/load.lua:91: Vim:E492: Not an editor command: PackerSync
Please check your config for correctness
```

I had no idea what to do, so I just ran the same command a couple more times.

Yeah It still failed, so from research I attempted to reinstall it but the same error appeared again and again, I tried `:PackerCompile`, but then it didn't recognize that command itself! I believe it may be most possible that something I configured does not do what I expected it to do, and thus causing the error. I greatly appreciate anyone who acknowledges and attempts to mitigate this issue. Thanks!